# Min-heap insertion function

Tags: c, heap

Here is an insertion function for min-heap. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
void insertHeapMin(Heap* h, int x){
if(isFull(h)){
    printf("heap is full\n");
    return;
}
for(i=0; i<h->size;i++) //I don't wan't to insert one number more than once; 
{
    if(x==h->data[i]) return;
}
int pos = h->size;
h->data[pos]=x;
while(pos>0){
    int parentPos = (pos-1)/2; 
    if (h->data[pos] < h->data[parentPos]){
        int temp = h->data[pos];
        h->data[pos] = h->data[parentPos];
        h->data[parentPos] = temp;
        pos = parentPos;
    } else
        break;
}
h->size++;
}
```

Main:

```
int a[] ={4,3,6,4,5};
size_t n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
Heap h;
initHeap(&h,100);
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    insertHeapMin(&h, a[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ",h.data[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

It returns 3 4 6 5 1666986547. I really can't see where is the mistake, when I modify the insertion function for max-heap it works perfectly, when there are no repeating elements, still don't see how to fix the for loop for repeating elements.

Comment: You don't insert an element twice, so your heap may have fewer than `n` elements. When you print out the heap, use `h.size` as limit.

Comment: It looks like 1666986547 is an int that is not initialized. Have you checked `n`? Maybe `n` is too large and you access `a[5]` by accident.

Comment: The comment from @MOehm is correct. the heap does not have `n` elements.

Comment: (By he way, the linear search for duplicates degrades your heap performance. It may be better to deal with duplicates when popping elements off the heap.)

Comment: Exactly, silly of me. Now it returns 3 4 6 5. I do not see why it won't sort properly...

Comment: @MOehm you have a lot to say, what about to say in an answer  ?

Comment: A heap is not fully sorted. It only has the condition that each parent is not greater than its children. (Sorting is achieved by popping items off the heap and re-heapifying.)

Comment: If you want to keep it sorted, you can find the insertion point from the initial iterative search for a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

First, where does the garbage value 1666986547 come from? This array element was not initialized, because you have duplicate elements, which you filter out before inserting. Your original array has length 5, your heap array has a length of only 4. Use the heap size `h.size` as limit when printing.

Second, why is the heap array not sorted? Heap arrays are only partially sorted: They satisfy the conditioon that the parent of any node must not be greater than any of its children. Your flat array

```
3 4 6 5
```

looks like this as heap:

```
    3
  4   6
5
```

The heap invariant is satisfied, but the ordering of the elements on each row is not determined. If you want to sort the array, pop off the top element until the heap is empty. After you remove the to element, fill the gaps repeatedly with the smaller child until you hit a leaf. In your heap, that looks like this:

```
    3           4           5           6
  4   6       5   6       6*   
5
```

In step 3, the six is moved (*), because you can't have gaps in the flat array.

I've commented that by doing a linear search for duplicates before inserting you degrade the perfromance of your heap. Each removal from the top and each insertion will visit log(n) elements – log(n) is the depth of your heap of n elements. By doing a linear search first, you make that n log(n).

Instead, insert all elements (at the cost of increased space if you have many duplicates). When you have removed the top element, re-heapify the heap until the new top element is different. That should give you better performance for most cases.

Comment: An alternative way to prevent duplicates is to maintain a hash table or similar data structure that keeps track of which items are in the heap. It's more memory, but doesn't degrade performance.